# model returns null on controller

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

i'm working with a a router and a controller, and i need to complete some operations on the controller, this is my model code

```
AcornsTest.StockRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    "use strict";
    var url_params = params.slug.split('|'),
      url = AcornsTest.Config.quandl.URL + '/' + url_params[0] + '/' + url_params[1] + '.json',
      stockInStore = this.store.getById('stock', url_params[1]),
      today =  new Date(),
      yearAgo = new Date(),
      self = this;

    yearAgo.setFullYear(today.getFullYear() - 1);
    today = today.getFullYear()+'-'+today.getMonth()+'-'+today.getDate();
    yearAgo = yearAgo.getFullYear()+'-'+yearAgo.getMonth()+'-'+yearAgo.getDate();

    if(stockInStore && stockInStore.get('data').length) {
      return stockInStore;
    }

    return Ember.$.getJSON(url,{ trim_start: yearAgo, trim_end: today, auth_token: AcornsTest.Config.quandl.APIKEY })
      .then(function(data) {
        if(stockInStore) {
           return stockInStore.set('data', data.data);
        } else {
           return self.store.createRecord('stock', {
            id: data.code,
            source_code: data.source_code,
            code: data.code,
            name: data.name,
            description: data.description,
            display_url: data.display_url,
            source_name: data.source_name,
            data: data.data,
            slug: data.source_code+'|'+data.code
          });
        }
    });
  }
});
```

and this is my controller

```
AcornsTest.StockController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  init: function() {
    "use strict";

    this.send('generateChartInfo');
  },

  actions: {
    generateChartInfo: function() {
      "use strict";

      console.log(this.model);
      console.log(this.get('model'));
    }
  }
});
```

from the controller i'm trying to get access to the model to get some information and format it, and send it to the view
but this.model or this.get('model') always returns null, how can i successful get access to the model from the controller? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding the `init` method, but its broken, do this:

```
AcornsTest.StockController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  init: function() {
    "use strict";
    this._super();

    this.send('generateChartInfo');
});
```

You need to call the parent method.

See this test case: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gijon/3/edit?js,console,output

The model is not ready at `init` time. If anyone has official docs please share.

Comment: just did the change, this is what i get on the console
    undefined
    null

Comment: init is when the controller is created, which happens before setupController.  In setupController the model is set on the controller.